# Delete reference to object but keep object in memory if referenced elsewhere

Tags: python, reference, garbage-collection

I am faced with the problem:
A function receives references to objects and calls del on those references at a certain point during its routine.

Those references refer to objects that are sometimes referenced elsewhere and that sometimes are not.

I would like the del statement to only delete the reference present in the function. If that object is not referenced to elsewhere in the program, it can be garbage collected.
If i'm correct, del directly calls the destructor of object rather than simply delete its reference.
How can i get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i'm correct, del directly calls the destructor of object rather than simply delete its reference.

Assuming CPython, this is incorrect.

`del` decreases the reference count of the object by 1. And the object is garbage collected when the reference count reaches 0.

If by *destructor* you meant the `__del__` magic method, note that it is *usually* called when the object is being garbage collected, not when `del` is called. Moreover, [there's no guarantee that the method would even be called](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

Just to note, there is also an (optional) `gc` interface that can break object reference cycles.

Comment: You are correct, I just tried it in a small code snippet in IPython and calling del doesn't seem to destroy my object if it is still referenced elsewhere.